# Removing punctuation from a text string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

Is there some way in Python3 to remove several unwanted characters from a string,
a way that is more efficient that removing each character one-by-one in a for-loop?

```
def RemovePunc( string ):
  punc = '\'";:.>,</?+=-_)(*&^%$#@!\`~'
  s = string
  for c in punc:
    s = s.replace(c,'')
  return s
```

Comment: Does this achieve what you want? https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub  i.e. `re.sub('[\'";:\.>,</?+=-_)(*&^%$#@!\`~]','',string)`

Comment: See [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: @jpf: Nice, regular expressions, `re.sub`. Excellent!

Comment: @NikolaosChatzis: Thanks for that link. Again, regex lead to more efficient methods.